# Как в Pandas удалять столбцы, где кол-во уникальных значений меньше 5%

Tags: python, pandas

Как в Pandas удалять столбцы, где кол-во уникальных значений меньше 5%
Есть датасет с 3000 столбцов и 5 строк.

Своего варианта не имею(
Прошу понять, простить, помочь)

Comment: Если там столбцы, в каждомиз котрых всего 5 строк -то кол-во уникальных значений в стобце может быть меньше 5 процентов только в том случае, если все 5 значений равны между собой, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @S.H., интересное наблюдение! Даже если все 5 значений в столбце одинаковые, то количество уникальных значений - 1/5 (20%). Таким образом решение задачи - не надо ничего делать :-D

Comment: @MaxU - да, это как раз была моя вторая гипотеза!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
threshold = 0.05
res = df.loc[:, (df.nunique() / len(df)) >= threshold]
```

PS если размерность вашего фрейма на самом деле - `(5, 3000)`, то вы таких столбцов не найдете, т.к. минимальное процентное соотношение уникальных значений в столбце с пятью значениями (5 строк) - это 1/5 или 20%.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пример! Вы правы, 5 столбцов не достаточно для выполнения условий. Но решение буду применять и на других данных.

Comment: @ИванИванов. [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)